# How to set a JsonProperty name for a feign bean field

Tags: java, rest, http, netflix-feign, feign

I need to create a bean for this json object.

```
{ "user_name" : "my-name" }
```

My java class is like this.

```
public class User {
    String username;
}
```

Is there any annotation to map `username` to `user_name` without changing the field name to `user_name`? Something like `@JsonProperty(name="user_name")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `@SerializedName("user_name")` annotation provided by gson instead.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using same DTO for feign and controller you should use both `@FormProperty` and `@JsonProperty`

Example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import feign.form.FormProperty;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class AccessTokenDto implements Serializable {
@JsonProperty("access_token")
@FormProperty("access_token")
private String accessToken;
...
}
```